# What could cause a furnace to short cycle?

Tags: hvac

- My Ducane MPGA100B4B furnace is shortcycling (2 minutes from fan on to fan off)
- The thermostat's Heat Anticipator setting doesn't seem to matter for the on-time, maybe the offtime changes
- The thermostat is of the round mechanical variety, not digital
- The furnace's control board seems to be blinking healthy codes - steady blink when off, faster steady blink when on.
- The air filter on the bottom left side of the unit doesn't seem too dirty.
- If I turn the thermostat to below-temp for a few seconds and then back above temp, the furnace will turn on again immediately for its 2 minutes.
- It's cold in here!

What might it be?  What can I check?

Comment: It is coding with Flame Failure Lockout blink now, but sometimes it goes back to a healthy blink.  The ignitor is out - there's 120v going to it when the relay kicks in, but it doesn't get hot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the temperature inside the furnace?  It is possible the pilot light went out.

*Disclaimer: I don't hold any special knowledge about furnaces.  They are dangerous if tampered with. Re-lighting pilot lights can blow your house up. I don't recommend anything.*

Comment: It has an ignitor, not a pilot light, but yes, that is broken.